# Проблема с функцией обобщенного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, функции

В книге Шилдта наткнулся на такой пример :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

template <class AType>

class atype {

    AType a[SIZE];

public:

    atype() {

        register int i;

        for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) a[i] = i;

    }

    AType &operator[](int i);

};

template <class АТуре>

АТуре &atype<AType>::operator[](int i)

{

    if (i<0 || i> SIZE - 1) {

        cout << "\n Значение индекса ";

        cout << i << " за пределами границ массива.\n";

    }

    return a[i];

}

int main()

{

    return 0;

}
```

При запуске у себя наткнулся на ошибку в этой строке :

```
АТуре &atype<AType>::operator[](int i)
```

"AType" не является допустимым аргументом типа шаблон для параметра "AType".
Как это исправить и почему "AType" не есть допустимым аргументом ?

Comment: "АТуре" написано кириллицей

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, Каким вообще образом можно допустить такую ошибку? Ладно ещё по ошибке набрать переменную `с` кириллицей, но `АТуре`... Копипаст из оцифрованной книги, где `AType` во время распознавания был опознан как набранный кириллицей?

Comment: @wololo ага, вроде и привык постоянно исправлять, но тут меня видимо смутило, что подсвечивается практически вся строка, а не одна переменная

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

template <class AType>
class atype {

    AType a[SIZE];

public:

    atype() {

        register int i;

        for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) a[i] = i;

    }

    AType &operator[](int i);

};

template <class AType> // тут AType похоже была кирилица (исправлено)
AType& atype<AType>::operator[](int i)

{

    if (i<0 || i> SIZE - 1) {

        cout << "\n Значение индекса ";

        cout << i << " за пределами границ массива.\n";

    }

    return a[i];

}

int main(int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    // смотри коды символов
    char a1[] = {'А', 'Т', 'у', 'р', 'е'}; // AType в объявлении
    char a2[] = {'A', 'T', 'y', 'p', 'e'}; // AType в определени

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не нужно хранить SIZE как глобальное переменное, лучше сделать ее аргументом шаблона